# Family $\mathcal{F}$ of functions $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ on open disk satisfies $|a_n|<n$ then every sequence has convergent subsequence.

Tags: complex-analysis

**Question**

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of all analytic functions $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ on the open unit disk $\mathbb{D}$  with $|a_n|<n$. Then every sequence in $\mathcal{F}$ has a subsequence that converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathcal{D}$.

**Attempt**

I have not seen this type of question before so I attempted to do it from first principles by fixing a compact set in $\mathbb{D}$ and showing that some subsequence of an arbitrary sequence $f_i=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^iz^n$ would satisfy cauchy's criterion for uniform convergence but I did not get anywhere with this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_family

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @Bumblebee's comment,

We must show that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally uniformly bounded. To this end, let $K$ be compact in $\mathbb{D}$. There exists $0<c<1$ such that for all $z\in K$, $|z|\leq c$. Consequently for any $f \in \mathcal{F}$, $|f|\leq \sum n c^n$. By the ratio test, this series converges (absolutely) so there exists a finite $M$ such that $|f| <M$.

Let me know if this is correct...

Comment: almost correct. but "By the ratio test, this series converges (absolutely) so $|f|\le M,$ where $M=\sum nc^n<\infty$." is better.

Comment: @ts375_zk26 Thanks! I incorporated your response into my answer.

Comment: "We must show that $\mathcal{F}$ is locally uniformly bounded." is better. Then your answer will be perfect.